# Prove uniqueness of polar-coordinates $(R>0, \theta)$ up to angle $\theta+ 2 \pi$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

> Prove uniqueness of polar-coordinates $(R>0, \theta)$ up to angle $\theta+ 2 \pi$.

Suppose we have $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. Then we can transform this point to polar-cordinates $(R>0, \theta)$ where the polar-coordinates are stated to be unique up to $\theta+ 2 \pi$ .

How do I show that no other point $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$ different from $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ doesn't have the same polar-coordinates ? I'm looking for an algebraic argument, not a "draw-and-see" argument.

I know I can prove uniquness of coordinate in $\mathbb R^n$ using linear algebra on the set $\{e_i\} $which form a basis.

More generally how are uniqueness of spherical coordinates proved ?

Comment: You also need to be a little careful about $R$. $R$ must be greater than $0$ for any sort of uniqueness. At $R = 0$, any value of $\theta$ would specify the origin. 
For uniqueness when $R \not= 0$, try playing around with the identities $(x, y) = (R \cos \theta, R \sin \theta).$

Comment: Do you plan to delete the present post after it gets some answers, as you deleted [this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768620/6179) with neither warning nor explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Uniquess of $R$ is easy, because $R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. For the angle you have to do some trigonometric work (or quote that $e^{i\theta}=1$ iff $\theta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$)